# How to retrieve users recent activity [audit] from google's api

Tags: angularjs, web-applications, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

We have a requirement to track the users recent activity, basically auditing and fetch those tracked details for further process. It is similar to **recent activity of a user in Linkedin?**

I checked [angular-google-analytics](https://github.com/revolunet/angular-google-analytics) github lib, it shows how to track users activity but there is no api to fetch user's activity

i also found google's [Real Time Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/) but that documentation made me more confuse.
I surveyed http://heapanalytics.com/, they also don't expose any API to fetch the tracked user data

Please suggest, how to take this forward.